# How to get the current currency code chosed by a site visitor in commerce

Tags: commerce

Is there a way to get the currency code chosed by a site visitor in drupal commerce?

Comment: This answer helped me: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/103662/get-current-currency-symbol-in-drupal-commerce