# How can I retrieve the current currency symbol?

Tags: commerce

I know there must be an API that returns the current currency symbol, but when I searched for it, I didn't find anything.

How can I retrieve the current currency symbol?

Answer (score 3):

With Drupal 7, if you want to get the default (current) currency you can use  the following code.

```php
$cur = commerce_currency_load();
$sym = $cur['symbol'];
```

Answer (score 3):

With the [Commerce Multicurrency](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_multicurrency) module and Drupal 7, you can use the following code.

```php
$enabled_curr = commerce_currencies(TRUE);
$current_curr = $enabled_curr[commerce_multicurrency_get_user_currency_code()];
$curr_symbol = $current_curr['symbol'];
```

Answer (score 3):

From Drupal 8, you can use the following code.

```php
// Add the following line on the top of the file using the rest of the code.
use Drupal\commerce_price\Entity\Currency;

// Get the currency code from the active store.
$currency_code = $store->get('default_currency')->getValue()[0]['target_id'];
$currency = Currency::load($currency_code);
$symbol = $currency->get('symbol');
```

Comment: Any specific reason not to use direct calls like `$store->getDefaultCurrencyCode()` or `$currency->getSymbol()`? Maybe these weren't available back then? They sure are now...

Answer (score 2):

With Drupal 8/9, if you are using the [commerce_currency_resolver](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_currency_resolver) module (which is pretty cool):

```
$currency_code = \Drupal::service('commerce_currency_resolver.current_currency')
                 ->getCurrency();
```